# PHP form multiple checkbox groups

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes in a from and I need to get values with php. Note that div class="group" can also be duplicated onruntime (with jquery) so I may end with multiple div class="group" of checkboxes.

Is there a way to set checkboxes name so form data gets grouped together for each "group", or whatever is easier to handles afterwards? There is also a problem of checkboxes that were not checked, so they wont be present in a post data.

I tried using names like this but I dont like the results.

```
<form>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[][time]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[][space]">                 
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[][money]">
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[][time]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[][space]">                 
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[][money]">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: depends how you want to handle the data server side. `ev[time][]` could be better could be worse, no way to know currently

Comment: Specify the index, `ev[0][time]`, `ev[1][time]` etc should be used, because a un-ticked checkbox's "empty" or "false" state will not be sent, messing up your array indexing. Basically use `row[0][key]` notation for simplest grouping

Comment: What's wrong with the result that you don't like it? I would use `ev1`... for the first group and `ev2`... for the second group.

Comment: If you had three sets of groups like above and ticked the first and third "time" checkbox skipping the middle one you would get `ev[0][time]` + `ev[1][time]` and not `ev[0][time]` + `ev[2][time]` when using the `[]` notation with checkbox fields. Much safer to be verbose with field names when grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining checkbox groups its much better to be verbose with input names and avoid using the `[]` notation.

A un-ticked checkbox is not sent in post data, and your selections will become misaligned.

```
<form>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[0][time]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[0][space]">                 
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[0][money]">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[1][time]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[1][space]">                 
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[1][money]">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[2][time]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[2][space]">                 
        <input type="checkbox" name="ev[2][money]">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I still dont get values in post for unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: And you never will, because that's how post data up works with checkboxes. What this code does is avoid any conflicting information by setting a unique index per group. The problem is if you don't check any boxes and submit the form you will not get the `ev` data at all, if you at least check the very last checkbox you will get `$_POST['ev'][2]['money']` and thus can iterate over `$_POST['ev']`. Fill in the gaps with your PHP code, you have no choice but to work around this "limitation" yourself.